# Inject JS file from FireBreath plugin?

Tags: npapi, firebreath, browser-plugin

I have FireBreath plugin, and some JS file in it. What I'm trying to do, at some point , inject that JS file using plugin. How is it possible to inject that js file using plugin? If you can please provide example, I'm new at it.

I need same behavior like NPN_Evaluate  does, are there any FireBreath API for that?

P.S. I'm aware of extensions, but for this particular case I need inject JS from plugin.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BrowserHost::evaluateJavascript()

From your main plugin class you can call this with m_host->evaluateJavascript(jsVar);

If you're trying to inject a file you'll have to load it from disk.  Another way, of course, would be to inject a script tag that loads it from disk, but that might require injecting javascript to do that with, 'cause I'm not sure if you can actually inject a script tag entirely through the plugin.